# I textured a model with materials, and they have disappeared

Tags: texturing, materials, weight-painting

The materials showed up perfectly fine. I spent a bit of time in weight paint, then my textures disappeared. They can be seen in cycles render, but based on an old save they were showing up fine in blender render. I also can't apply any new materials either.

Comment: Materials created for cycles do not work in blender render.

Comment: I originally textured the model in blender render and it worked fine